# Optimal strategy of a lucky wheel game with multiple spins allowed until 0 is selected

Tags: probability

In a lucky wheel game, the wheel is divided into 10 equal parts.

3 of them are +1, 3 of them are +2, 3 of them are +3, the remaining one is 0.

**When 0 is selected**, the game is over and the player **loses all the money** earned in all of the previous rounds.

The player can spin as much as the player want. That means **multiple spins are allowed until 0 is selected**.

Therefore, for every spin, there is 90% chance to win money and 10% chance to lose all.

---

In light of this, if the player is very greedy and want to gain like $100. It is very likely that the player loses all the money. However, if the player is too cautious and only spin 1 time and collect the money. It seems that the player does not maximize its potential gain.

So, I want to know the **optimal strategy** in this game. That means when should the player stops, such as until nth spins or until a certain amount of money is accumulated.

My assumption is that after nth spin, the expected value of accumulated money is decreased, and thus the player should stop at nth spin. However, I cannot solve the problem using my knowledge. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

ps. sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your idea is excellent. To take it further suppose the player has won $n$ so far. If he spins again, then his expected win is $$0.3\times1+0.3\times2+0.3\times3-0.1\times n=1.8-0.1n=0.1(18-n)$$ So there is no expected benefit in playing after he has accumulated winnings of 18 or more.

A particular player might have a "non-linear utility curve". In other words after he has won say 10, he might have little interest in winning more, but much interest in not losing his winnings. But without more information we make the simple assumption that the player continues to spin until his expected return ceases to be positive.